# Difference between :app:assembleRelease and assembleRelease

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I have mutiple modules in my android project. if i make a release apk with `:app:assembleRelease` it works but when i make a release apk with `assembleRelease` it keep showing error. I know there's error in my code but this is not what i am questioning about. I just want to know what is the difference between `assembleRelease` and `:app:assembleRelease`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Multi module Gradle project, if you don't refer to your module *explicitly* then Gradle by default try to find that task from root project's Tasks graph.

*For example*: If you're having multiple modules named as **module1** & **module2**, then on evaluation phase Gradle distributes each module's tasks in their own extensions. Meaning you must now refer it as **`:module1:task1`** & **`:module2:task2`**

This is the reason why `assembleRelease` doesn't work & `:app:assembleRelease` works.

---

You can check tasks graph by opening 'Gradle' window in Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA.

If you look at the image below you can see Tasks node which have common tasks available at root project.

While there are other module related tasks can be found inside expanding it's own node.

[image: Gradle Task Graph]

***Note that***: In android you can have multiple modules but your default module is always abbreviated as app module while others are considered as library module which are abbreviated by name of that individual module like base, db, domain etc. from image above *(You can't have multiple app module in same project I guess)*.

Comment: what will be happened if i run `:db:assembleRelease` instead of `:app:assembleRelease`?

Comment: It would generate .aar *(android archive format)* file for that module library inside it's build directory.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between `:app:assembleRelease` and `assembleRelease` is that `assembleRelease` executes the `assembleRelease` task of each module while `:app:assembleRelease` executes the `assembleRelease` task in the `app` module.

Obviously the task graph is populated correctly for both, it means that `:app:assembleRelease` for Android depends on the `assembleRelease` of the other modules used as dependencies in `:app`.

Comment: is it okay if i make an android apk for playstore with `:app:assembleRelease` instead of `assembleRelease`?

Comment: @zihadrizkyef If the APK you are upload on Play Store is the APK of the module `app` and you aren't manually manipulating the task graph, yes.