# What is the difference between gradlew assembleRelease vs gradlew app:assembleRelease?

Tags: react-native, gradlew

For some reasons `./gradlew assembleRelease` fails with

```
Task :react-native-splash-screen:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
```

Saw a comment [here](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/393#issuecomment-519843778) suggesting

```
./gradlew app:assembleRelease
```

instead and it works.

What's the difference between `./gradlew assembleRelease` and `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`?

Comment: Kind of duplicate, here are some answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990805/difference-between-appassemblerelease-and-assemblerelease